# How to use same partial with variables from different controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application, users submit reviews under brands. Here's the association:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :reviews

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :brand
```

Right now I have a partial defined to show reviews as such:

_showreview.html.erb

```
<% review.each do |review| %>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
<%= image_tag review.first_photo %>
<div class="caption">
<h4><%= link_to review.title, review %></h4>
<h6><strong><%= link_to ("WRITTEN BY " + review.user.username.upcase), review.user %></strong></h6>
<%= review.description.truncate_words(60, omission: '...') %>
<br>    
<br>
<%= link_to review.brand.label, review.brand, :class => 'btn btn-sm btn-lake' %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And I render it like this by passing an instance variable in:

```
<%= render "showreview", review: @top_reviews %>
```

It works as expected.

Now I wish to reuse the partial for brands/show.html.erb

What I want to do now is retrieve all the reviews that belong to a brand and display it.

show_controller.rb looks like this

```
 def show
  @brand = Brand.find(params[:id])
 @reviews =Review.find(params[:id])
 end
```

I tried to use this but it doesn't work. What is the correct way to do this?

```
<%= render "/reviews/showreview", review: '@brand.reviews' %>
```

Comment: You can specify the partial view lie  <%= render "brands/showreview", review: `your reviews variable` %>

Comment: Do you want to show single review ?

Comment: No I want to show all the reviews that belong to a brand. Thanks.

Comment: I added answer. please accept it. if it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= render "/reviews/showreview", review: @brand.reviews %>
```

But please, rename `review` to `reviews`. It's more convenient name of this variable.

Comment: He don't want to do this

Comment: Try like this `<%= render partial: "/reviews/showreview", locals: { review: @brand.reviews } %>`

Answer (score 0):

Your method will be like this

```
def show
  @brand = Brand.find(params[:id])
end
```

and in your view

```
 <%= render "reviews/showreview", review: @brand.reviews %>
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you should use a plurality for the variable review instead.

```
reviews.each do |review|
```

it makes your code readability.
then try placing review: '@branch.review' by `reviews: @branch.reviews`
and make sure that you did pass the variable @branch from your controller